# How use Bash to change multiple filenames case to match another directory?

Tags: bash, case, minecraft

I am migrating from one YAML based system to another, merging the data from one management style to the next.

In `path/to/directory/one/`, the filenames are `foobar1.yml`, `foobar2.yml`, ... 
In `path/to/new/directory/two/` , the filenames are `FooBar1.yml`, `FooBar3.yml`, ...

In the original system, in `path/to/directory/other/` there are  filenames `FooBar1.dat`, `FooBar2.dat`. These match 1:1 with the files in `path/to/directory/one/`, with the exception that they have the correct case and different extensions and file contents.

I would like to use bash to read each of files in `path/to/directory/one/`, grab the lines that I need to import, change one of the lines, and write them to the correct corresponding file in `path/to/new/directory/two/` matching the correct case, creating a new file if that file does not exist already.

Specifically, I am attempting to migrate a Minecraft plugin's data from Essentials to AdminCmd and WorldPos.

Here are examples of the various files and formats: http://pastebin.com/PMtCMXGt

First question here, so please let me know if I am being too specific or vague.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
cd path/to/directory/one/
for f in *.yml
do
    grep 'whatyouwant' $f >> path/to/new/directory/two/$(sed 's/foobar/FooBar/' <<<$f)
done
```

We use a `bash` "here string" to build the new file names

Comment: Perhaps this might work, but the filenames aren't all FooBar, but rather usernames, such as foojoe.yml, barnone732.yml, ohmygodausername.yml, and in the other directory FooJoe.dat, BarNone732.dat, OhMyGodAUserName.dat.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the base of something which I think you can use. Let me know if it comes in handy or lacking

```
DIRONE=/path/to/dir/one
DIROTHER=/path/to/dir/other

for f in $DIRONE/*.yml
do
    basename $f
done | sed -e 's/(.+)\.yml/\1/' | while read name; 
    do

            # find a matching .dat file in $DIRTWO
            for f2 in $DIROTHER/*.dat
            do
                    basename $f2
            done | sed -r 's/(.+)\.dat/\1 \L\1/' | while read nameOrig nameLower; 
                    do
                            if [ $nameLower -eq $name ]; then
                                    #nameLower is foobar1.yml in /path/to/dir/one
                                    #nameHigher is FooBar1.dat in /path/to/dir/two
                                    echo "$nameOrig matches $name"
                                    break;
                            fi
                    done
    done
```